# Circuitikz: incorrect position of displaystyle fraction in bipoles (e.g. inductors, capacitors)

Tags: circuitikz, fractions, displaystyle

I have met a problem when drawing a circuit. I want to draw a circuit with "fraction" in label such as `L/2`, `R_1/4`, etc. However, if I use `\dfrac`, the denominator will overlap with some part of the bipole (an inductor in this sample code). Using `\frac` to represent fraction gives correct position, but it makes the font size of the argument in its denominator and numerator smaller, which I want to avoid.

In short,I want **the position of the label content,** `\dfrac{L_3}{2}`**, a little higher than the north anchor of the inductor**.

[image: output of sample code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}\draw
        (0,0) to[L,l=$\dfrac{L_3}{2}$] (2,0) node[right]{label position should be slightly higher}
        (0,2) to[L,l=$\frac{L_3}{2}$] (2,2) node[right]{font size of $L_3$ is incorrect (not in displaystyle)}
        (0,4) to[L,l=$L_3$] (2,4) node[right]{font size is correct but it is not a fraction}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say I prefer the small `\frac`. `\dfrac` is way too big for this.

Comment: I want to keep the font size of all the circuit variables identical, so I do not apply `\frac` in this example.

Comment: You can use `\ctikzset{bipole label style/.style={above=-3pt,inner sep=0pt}}` where the -3pt is a fudge factor based on aesthetics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always make use of non-Ti*k*Z commands:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw
  (0,0) to[L,l=\raisebox{7pt}{$\dfrac{L_3}{2}$}] (2,0) node[right]{label position should be slightly higher}
  (0,2) to[L,l=\raisebox{2pt}{$\frac{L_3}{2}$}] (2,2) node[right]{font size of $L_3$ is incorrect (not in displaystyle)}
  (0,4) to[L,l=$L_3$] (2,4) node[right]{font size is correct but not it is not a fraction}
  ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly the desired result.

thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference. I adopt @Fractal 's approach since it is more concise and more readable.

I offer another workaround that utilizes **only tikz commands** but it is **more verbose**.

I add a node name to the inductor and then access its anchor (south in this case) to add text description, i.e. placing `\dfrac{L_3}{2}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}\draw
        (0,0) to[L,name=ind] (2,0) node[right]{label position should be slightly higher}
        (0,2) to[L,l=$\frac{L_3}{2}$] (2,2) node[right]{font size of $L_3$ is incorrect (not in displaystyle)}
        (0,4) to[L,l=$L_3$] (2,4) node[right]{font size is correct but it is not a fraction}
        (ind.north) node[above] {$\dfrac{L_3}{2}$} % add a new node to locate anchor properly
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code]